# Track behavioral flow from google tag manager event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to see which pages a visitor went through, when filling in a contact form. To track the submitting of the form, I setup google tag manager with google analytics.

So now when submitted I see an event "FormSubmitted" in Analytics.
Only now I can't get to figure out, how I can check the behavior flow of only the user which submitted the form.

Is anyone known with this, and knows how to filter that specific usertype out? Tried some filters in the behavior flow section, but couldn't get the right one.

Hope to get a solution here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only now I can't get to figure out, how I can check the behavior flow of only the user which submitted the form.

Create a segment with conditions for example "Sessions includes event category = ...".
And apply it on report "Behavior Flow".

Ussually to track steps of form filling it's better to set it before. You need to set sending virtual pages in GTM for each step you want and then create goal in GA type Destination and add steps there. After successful setup you'll see funnel in report 'Funnel Visualization'.